# UIO device files /dev/uioX are not created on Linux Debian

Tags: debian, systemd, drivers, udev, devices

I'm having a problem on Linux Debian 9.6. Although I have UIO support compiled into the kernel, the `/dev/uioX` device files are not beeing created.

```
root@machine:~# zcat /proc/config.gz | grep UIO
CONFIG_UIO=y
# CONFIG_UIO_CIF is not set
CONFIG_UIO_PDRV_GENIRQ=y
CONFIG_UIO_DMEM_GENIRQ=y
# CONFIG_UIO_AEC is not set
# CONFIG_UIO_SERCOS3 is not set
CONFIG_UIO_PCI_GENERIC=y
# CONFIG_UIO_NETX is not set
# CONFIG_UIO_PRUSS is not set
# CONFIG_UIO_MF624 is not set
```

There is an entry in the `sysfs` though:

```
root@machine:~# ls -la /sys/class/uio/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Nov 26 10:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 44 root root 0 Nov 26 10:00 ..
```

Seems as if `udevd` does not create the device files, any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIO device nodes are only allocated when a device is registered, *e.g.* when you probe a PCI device using the generic PCI UIO driver:

```
echo "8086 10f5" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/uio_pci_generic/new_id
```

In the driver, this corresponds to a `uio_register_device` call.

See [the UIO howto](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/uio-howto.html) for details.